# Does $a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

$a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} + ... +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}$

and I need to check whether this sequence converges to a limit without finding the limit itself. I think about using the squeeze theorem that converges to something (I suspect '$1$').

But I wrote $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n-1}$ and it doesn't get me anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} + \cdots +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$$
$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} + \cdots +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\le\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} + \cdots +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{n\sqrt{1+\frac2n-\frac1{n^2}}}\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} + \cdots +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{n\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}$$
$$1\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} + \cdots +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\le1$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} + \cdots +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}=1$$

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote? If anything is wrong, I would edit/delete the answer.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the formatting could be largely improved.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you just have to consider that
$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\ge a_{n} \ge  \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}$$
Then take the limit and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand,

$$a_n \ge \mbox{smallest summand} \times \mbox{number of summands}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}\times  n .$$

To deal with the denominator, observe that

$$n^2+2n-1 \le n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2.$$

On the other hand,

$$a_n \le \mbox{largest  summand}\times \mbox{number of summands} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\times n.$$

To deal with the denominator, observe that

$$n^2+n \ge n^2$$.