# Finding limit of the sequences: $a_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+n}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}+\dots+\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}$ and $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n+k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I have a sequence and I need to find the limit, it's written in a form that confuses me, what's the methodology to solve limits like this:

> \begin{align*}
> a_n&=\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+n}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+n+2}}+\dots+\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}\\
> b_n&=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}+\dots+\frac1{\sqrt{n+n}}
> \end{align*}

[image]

Comment: the first limit is 1 it is a Riemann sum

Comment: your second sum does not converges

Comment: The second question has been previously asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522504/finding-limit-to-the-following-series-with-n-addends). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%2B2%7D%7D%2B%5Ccdots%2B%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%2Bn%7D%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690092/does-a-n-frac1-sqrtn2n-frac1-sqrtn2n1-frac1) is about the first sequence. But it does not ask about the value of the limit, only whether it converges. Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E2%2Bn%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E2%2Bn%2B1%7D%7D%2B%5Ccdots%2B%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E2%2B2n%7D%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you can justify/explain the following steps:

$$\begin{align*}&(i)\;\;1\xleftarrow[\infty\leftarrow n]{}\frac n{n+2}\le\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}\le\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+n+k}}\le\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le\frac{n+1}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\\{}\\&(ii)\;\;\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n+k}}\ge\frac n{\sqrt{2n}}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

First part :

$$a_n = \frac 1{\sqrt {n^2+n}}+\frac 1{\sqrt {n^2+n+1}}+\frac 1{\sqrt {n^2+n+2}} +....+\frac 1{\sqrt {n^2+2n}}$$

Now we are going to use Sandwich Theorem -

Replace all the denominators by $\sqrt {n^2+n}$

Thus we have increased the value of $a_n$;

$$a_n \le  \frac n{\sqrt {n^2+n}}$$

Applying limit $n \rightarrow \infty$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \le  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac n{\sqrt {n^2+n}} = 1$$

$$\implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \le  1$$
Now replace all the denominators by $\sqrt {n^2+2n}$

Thus we have decreased the value of $a_n$;

$$a_n \ge  \frac n{\sqrt {n^2+2n}}$$

Applying limit $n \rightarrow \infty$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \ge  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac n{\sqrt {n^2+2n}} = 1$$

$$ \implies  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \ge  1$$
Combining both the results, we get :

$$1 \le \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n \le  1$$

Therefore :

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=1$$

Now follow same procedure to find $b_n$

You will find,
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$ doesn't exist